# Ansible Cloudwatch rule reports failed invocations

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created an AWS lambda that works well when I test it and when I create a cron job manually through a cloudwatch rule.

It reports metrics as invocations (not failed) and also logs with details about the execution.

Then I decided to remove that manually created cloudwatch rule in order to create one with ansible.

```
  - name: Create lambda service.
    lambda:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      state: present
      zip_file: "{{ item.zip_file }}"
      runtime: 'python2.7'
      role: 'arn:aws:iam::12345678901:role/lambda_ecr_delete'
      handler: 'main.handler'
      region: 'eu-west-2'
      environment_variables: "{{ item.env_vars }}"
    with_items:
      - name: lamda_ecr_cleaner
        zip_file: assets/scripts/ecr-cleaner.zip
        env_vars:
          'DRYRUN': '0'
          'IMAGES_TO_KEEP': '20'
          'REGION': 'eu-west-2'
    register: new_lambda

  - name: Schedule a cloudwatch event.
    cloudwatchevent_rule:
      name: ecr_delete
      schedule_expression: "rate(1 day)"
      description: Delete old images in ecr repo.
      targets:
        - id: ecr_delete
          arn: "{{ item.configuration.function_arn }}"
    with_items: "{{ new_lambda.results }}"
```

That creates almost the exact same cloudwatch rule. The only difference I can see with the manually created one is in the targets, the lambda version / alias is set to Default when created manually while it is set to version, with a corresponding version number when created with ansible.

The cloudwatch rule created with ansible has only failed invocations.

Any idea why this is? I can't see any logs. Is there a way I can set the version to Default as well with the cloudwatchevent_rule module in ansible?

Comment: have you solved this? I am encountering similar issue. Ansible creation succeeds but events fail. If I edit and save the event rule (no changes) it starting to work...

Comment: No I have not found a solution to that. If you find one please let me know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've lost hours with this too, same error and same confusion (Why there isn't a log for failed invokations?), I'm going to share my ""solution"", it will solve the problem to someone, and will help others to debug and find the ultimate solution.

**Note: Be carefull, this could allow any AWS account execute your lambda functions**

Since you got invoke the function by creating the rule target manually, I assume you added the invoke permission to the lambda from CloudWatch, however it looks like the Source Account ID is different when the event is created by cli/api and when is created by de AWS dashboard/console

If you are adding the Source Account condition in the lambda invoke permission from principal "events.amazonaws.com" to prevent any AWS account execute your lambdas just remove it (under your responsability!).

So, if your lambda policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Sid": "<sid>",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",,
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "AWS:SourceAccount": "<account-id>"
        }
    },
    "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<account-id>:function:<lambda-function>"
}
```

Remove the "Condition" field

```
{
    "Sid": "sid",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",,
    "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<account-id>:function:<lambda-function>"
}
```

And "maybe" it will work for you.

I think something weird it is happening with the cloudwatch event owner/creator data when the event is created by cli/api... maybe a bug? Not sure. I will keep working on it

Comment: Amazing. Lost a couple of hours with that one. We have been creating various different types of trigger for Lambda functions and all of them have worked when including the AWS:SourceAccount. Events seems to be different. I guess they must originate from a different account. The scheduler itself may not run inside our own AWS account.

Comment: Exactly. I was creating S3 triggers for Lambda functions including the AWS:SourceAccount condition with no problems, however with CloudWatch events created with aws-cli does not work, if you do it with the dashboard runs well. I think the event owner is not being rightly defined when is created by api.

Comment: I was having this problem creating the CloudWatch rule via Terraform. This post oriented me towards the solution and this is what is needed in Terraform: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_permission.html

Answer (score 7):

To extend the answered here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CWE_Troubleshooting.html#LAMfunctionNotInvoked. Since you are creating it via API you should add permission to Lambda as mentioned before. Without compromising security you could do the following:

Add rule with `PutRule` api call, it will return you

```
{
   "RuleArn": "string"
}
```

Use the `RuleArn` in Lambda AddPermission call

```
aws lambda add-permission \
--function-name MyFunction \
--statement-id MyId \
--action 'lambda:InvokeFunction' \
--principal events.amazonaws.com \
--source-arn arn-from-PutRule-request
```

Comment: Not viable solution if you want to have (a lot of) dynamically created rules since you will hit lambda policy limits (20kb).

Comment: It is viable if you use a wildcard in the `source-arn`, something like: `arn:aws:events:<region>:<account-id>:rule/* `

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the reason your invocations are failing, see the other answers UNLESS you're trying to implement AWS::Events::Rule and you're seeing failed invocations. The following answer may resolve the issue and negate to need to find these non-existent logs.

[Cloudwatch failedinvocation error no logs available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63854503/901899)